# a plugin version that doesn't match the code will there be a problem?

Tags: kotlin, gradle

I want to install gradle 7.2 into a finished android project (because there is no gradle), but in gradle 7.2 the plugin version must be included, if the version I enter doesn't match the code, will there be a problem? is there a solution so that the project can be installed gradle and run?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there should be a problem. You have to install a compatible version or create a new project with the desired version and import the files in that.

Comment: if the plugin in gradle has no version will it automatically use the latest version?